# Is there a way to make a Datepicker round? (JavaFX)

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-css

I've been trying to customize with css my JavaFX application...so far so good untill I reach the Datepicker... I tried a lot of different aproaches but none of them seem to work. Is there a way to make the Datepicker round just like my TextFields?

Actual JavaFX interface that I'm working on:
[image: Actual JavaFX interface that I'm working on]

(btw, I'm using Java 8_111 with Netbeans 8.2 if that helps on something)

Greetings!

Comment: Can you post your CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to individually set the `background-radius` for the `date-picker` itself, plus it's underlying `text-field` and `arrow-button` (which is the calendar button).

For example, using the following CSS:

```
.date-picker {
    -fx-background-radius: 10 10 10 10;
}
.date-picker > .text-field {
    -fx-background-radius: 10 0 0 10;
}

.date-picker > .arrow-button {
    -fx-background-radius: 0 10 10 0;
}
```

Produces this `DatePicker`:

[image: screenshot]

---

For future CSS styling needs, you can learn a lot by referencing the default [modena.css](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) stylesheet used internally by JavaFX. This is valuable for learning many of the additional selectors available which aren't described in the "official" [CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

Comment: I just wonder if you need the `border-radius`? AFAIK borders are not set on most controls (the *popup* associated with the date picker is an exception, but not the date picker itself).

Comment: Ah; right you are, @James_D. I will update my answer.